# Is firebase not always sending notifications through APNs?

Tags: ios, firebase, apple-push-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

I noticed that the [firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref) says the following:

> If a notification **payload** is provided, or the **content_available**
>   option is set to **true** for a message to an iOS device, the message is
>   sent through APNs, otherwise it is **sent through the FCM connection
>   server**.

Can someone please explain what that means?

I thought ALL push notifications sent to iOS devices, are first sent to **Apple**, and then forwarded by Apple to the corresponding device/s, but here it is implied that they're sending messages directly to the device?

Is that even possible when the app is shut on iOS?

I'm confused,
thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the app is in the foreground, FCM can connect directly rather than go via APNs for `data` type messages. Messages sent when in the background are delivered via APNs as you'd expect. You can actually take a look at the [source of the FCM client](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/blob/master/Firebase/Messaging/FIRMessagingConnection.h#L57) if you're so inclined!

You can control whether this is used with the [shouldEstablishDirectChannel](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasemessaging/api/reference/Classes/FIRMessaging#/c:objc(cs)FIRMessaging(py)shouldEstablishDirectChannel) property.

From the sending perspective, you don't need to worry too much about this - its handled transparently as part of the FCM service based on the type of the message and whether there is a client connected.

Comment: Here's what I don't get: The documentation on the link is about their http API, and not their objective-C sdk (fcm client).
Firebase has so many tools and services that it's super cryptic to figure what they mean.

Why would they add information about the client SDK in a page that describes how to call their web http api?

That still makes no sense.

Comment: Disclaimer: I work on Firebase! The reason for the note is just that some folks were seeing messages they sent that were not sent through APNs, and wondered why. Its tricky to find a good home for that kind of stuff! content-available is an iOS specific field, which is why it includes the iOS detail.

Comment: Quick question about that Ian, can fcm-to-device direct connection create a visible notification (by dispatching a local notification on the client side of the device that receives it), or does that channel only work for data-only messages, that don't need to be displayed to the user?

Answer (score 2):

From my understanding after reading the document, it might be trying to state that:

*If the notification can be inferred to be targeted to an iOS device* (whether from notification payload or the content-available key), it bypasses FCM and gets sent to APNS directly for optimization as it's known  for 100% to be destined to APNS anyway.

Otherwise, it will be sent to FCM and be routed to wherever it should go from there. It might still be a notification for an iOS device and be sent to APNS from FCM, but it just can't be inferred.

Comment: Wait, I still don't get it, but this documentation is for making calls to FCM anyway, via their http API (it is not documentation for their sdk is it?)

Are you suggesting that this call doesn't invoke an http request to fcm if we're making it from their SDK, but instead it sends the data to APNS directly if there's no notification payload or the content-available key?

Comment: Kinda. I still don't understand how it can whether it's an iOS notification or not by just checking presence of notification payload (it *can* infer if it checks the inner values anyway), but the general idea is yes, if it can infer that it's targeted to iOS, it skips FCM and connects to APNS directly. Again, I haven't checked the actual SDK, **this is just my understanding after reading the doc**.

Comment: Ι don't think the documentation refers to their sdk, I think it's plain HTTP requests, and there's no logic implemented anywhere to do that if we're just calling their web api.